# Can Jacoco CLI report be filtered via classfiles

Tags: jacoco

Is it possible to report only for 1 or selective class(es) out of a jar file, So for example *.exec is recorded for an application but report is needed for only 1 class, now in `--classfiles` we can specify a JAR file like /path/trial.jar but not beyond that like /path/trial.jar/pkg1/class, Is there some option to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<path>` in `--classfiles <path>` is scanned recursively and all found class files are used for generation of report, so it can point not only on JAR files, but also on directories containing JAR files and class files, as well as can point on a single class file.

For example after compilation of `Example.java`

```
class Example {

  class Inner {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  }

}
```

into directory `classes`

```
javac Example.java -d classes
```

two class files will be produced as can be seen by command `ls classes`

```
'Example$Inner.class'   Example.class
```

After generation of `jacoco.exec`

```
java -cp classes -javaagent:jacoco-0.8.0/lib/jacocoagent.jar Example
```

possible to generate report for whole `classes` directory using command

```
java -jar jacoco-0.8.0/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles classes
```

and two class files will be analyzed

```
[INFO] Loading execution data file /tmp/example/jacoco.exec.
[INFO] Analyzing 2 classes.
```

or generate report for single `Example.class` using command

```
java -jar jacoco-0.8.0/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles classes/Example.class
```

and only this class will be analyzed

```
[INFO] Loading execution data file /tmp/example/jacoco.exec.
[INFO] Analyzing 1 classes.
```

So you can unpack JAR file into directory and analyze separately whatever you want in it.

Comment: Feels like my foot in my mouth, So obvious but it did not occur to me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AnubhavBansal instead of just addition of comment please mark answer as accepted and upvote it